# Can't Find Llamas!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I watched a video and it said that llamas were added in the newest update in minecraft, and the youtuber had llamas standing in a pen she had made. I told my friend, so she totally checked to make sure. But when she said there were no llamas, I was really confused. Plus, there were no mods like that, so then we became even **MORE** confused. the youtuber was Ldshadowlady, and I watch her a lot. I am so confused!!! Are they really in minecraft?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [llamas](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Llama) were added in the latest update, Minecraft 1.11. They spawn in only two biomes though: Extreme Hills and Savanna. Even if you already have a save with some Extreme Hills or Savanna nearby though, to find llamas you will likely have to either start a new world, or explore into parts of an existing world you haven't visited yet.

This is because animals already in a chunk prevent any more from spawning, so in a world that was started in a version of Minecraft before llamas were added to the game, all the land you have already visited has already filled its “quota” of animals with every other kind of animal, and no new animals (including new llamas) will spawn there. Hence why going to unexplored parts of a map is necessary, or starting a fresh save.